# i was trying to install expo cli on my system and it showed me this error

Tags: expo

(node:13388) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

i tried installing from beginning but it occured again